# Wrong x-dots in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need render graph with the same placement dots and x-axis labels. 
If minimum date matches with start of week - all ok (graph1),
otherwise dots and x-axis label differ (graph 2)

[Sample](http://goo.gl/wYZUjT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to use `tickPositioner` to change default ticks, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v0eyt5eL/2/

```
tickPositioner: function(min,max) {
    return this.series[0].processedXData.slice(); // get copy of the series x-positions
},
```